# PyQt4 close tab that request closing

Tags: python, tabs, pyqt4, qtabwidget

I cannot find a way to close the tab that request to be closed. I only found how to close current widget and current tab. Any ideas? I can't find a clue on internet.

```
self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.removeTab)

def removeTab(self):
    tab = self.tabs.currentWidget()
    tab.deleteLater()
```

Answer (score 3):

The `QTabWidget` class has a [removeTab](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#removeTab) method, which will remove a tab, but without deleting its content widget. So you will also need to delete the content widget explicitly:

```
    self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.removeTab)
    ...

    def removeTab(self, index):
        widget = self.tabs.widget(index)
        if widget is not None:
            widget.deleteLater()
        self.tabs.removeTab(index)
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but now i have another trouble. Every time the tab is closed, index changes and next tabs are also closed i.e. closing tab 5, also 6,7,8 are closed, but not 1,2,3,4.

Comment: @marcusvanloer. Without seeing actual code, it's hard to say what you're doing wrong. I suppose if you had somehow connected the `tabCloseRequested` signal multiple times it would explain that behaviour - but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I can post you the code, but it's a bit confused.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import codecs
import os

class Central_widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, setted_lang):
         super(Central_widget, self).__init__()

        #tab list
        self.tab_list = {}
        self.cont_list = {}
        self.label_list = {}
        self.label_num = 0
        self.tab_num = 0

        #main page contenent
        lesson = codecs.open('lessons\lekcja.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8' )
        self.read = lesson.read()
        read2 = self.read.encode('utf8')
        print read2

        #General widget
        self.general = QWidget(self)
        self.general.resize(900, 700)

        #leftWidget
        self.leftWidget=QWidget(self.general)
        self.leftWidget.resize(160 ,657)

        #tab master
        self.tabmaster(self.general)


    def tabmaster(self, general):

        #left widget
        self.scrollarea()

        #right widget
        self.tabs = QTabWidget(self.general)
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabs.setTabEnabled(self.tab_num, True)
        self.tabs.resize(710, 640)
        self.tabs.move(170, 9)

        #actual open tabs
        self.actual_numtabs = self.tabs.indexOf(self.tabs.currentWidget())

        #homepage tab
        self.new_tab('hey')      

     def new_tab(self, text):
    #tab_name - tab_value dictionary
        if self.tab_num == 0:
            name_new_tab = 'Homepage'
        else: name_new_tab = 'Karta '+str(self.tab_num)
    value_new_tab = QWidget()
    self.tab_list[name_new_tab] = value_new_tab

    #tab_content and cont_value
        tab_content = 'cont '+str(self.tab_num)
        cont_value = QTextBrowser(self.tab_list[name_new_tab])
        self.cont_list[tab_content] = cont_value

    #set size, text, add widget to tab
    self.tabs.addTab(self.tab_list[name_new_tab], str(name_new_tab))
    self.cont_list[tab_content].setFixedSize(704, 614)

    if self.tab_num == 0:
            self.cont_list[tab_content].setText(self.read)
            self.tabs.setCurrentWidget(self.tab_list[name_new_tab])
        else: self.cont_list[tab_content].setText(text)

        #close tab
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.removeTab)

        self.tab_num += 1

    def removeTab(self, index):
        #remove tab from widget
        widget = self.tabs.widget(index)
        if widget is not None:
            widget.deleteLater()
        self.tabs.removeTab(index)

    def scrollarea(self):

        #scroll area
        layoutleft = QVBoxLayout(self.leftWidget)
        s=QScrollArea()
        layoutleft.addWidget(s)
        widleft = QWidget(self)
        vbox=QVBoxLayout(widleft)
        nl=QHBoxLayout()
        nl.addWidget(QLabel(u"Lista lekcji dostępnych:", self))
        vbox.addLayout(nl)
        nl=QHBoxLayout()
        vbox.addLayout(nl)
        vbox.setSpacing(2)
        vbox.insertSpacing(1, 20)

        #list of lessons
        for filename in os.listdir('lessons'):
            name = os.path.splitext(filename)
            label_var = name[0]
            value = QPushButton(label_var)
            self.label_list[label_var] = value
            self.label_list[label_var].clicked.connect(self.openlesson)
            self.label_list[label_var].setObjectName(label_var)
            _l=QHBoxLayout()
            _l.addWidget(self.label_list[label_var])
            vbox.addLayout(_l)

        s.setWidget(widleft)

    def openlesson(self):
        a = self.sender()
        print a.objectName()
        lesson = codecs.open('lessons\\'+str(a.objectName())+'.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8' )
        read = lesson.read()
        self.new_tab(read)
```

Comment: As I guessed, you are adding a connection to `tabCloseRequested` every time `newtab` is called, which means it will fire multiple times. So move that line out of the `newtab` method, and put it in the `tabmaster` method, so the connection is only made once.